# Will a C conditional always return 1 or 0?

Tags: c, standards, conditional-statements

Do C conditional statements always return [1 or 0], or do they return [0 or 'something other than zero']. I ask because:

pseudo code -

> foo(address, shouldSend):
>   register >>= 1
>   register <<= 1 // to clear bit in first position
>   register |= shouldSend // to signal whether it should send or not

the problem occurs if somebody passin IN a shouldSend value of true greater than one (as only 0 is false and all else is true, technically this is valid). since i am directly OR'ing the truth value of shouldSend with the register, it better not be say 0xFF! i already have a solution, so the question is more for curiousity sake. i am wondering though if:

> foo(address, shouldSend):
>   register >>= 1
>   register <<= 1 // to clear bit in first position
>   register |= **(shouldSend > 0)** // to signal whether it should send or not

solves the problem? i would think that now the problem of an 0xFF(or in general, something greater than 1) passed in is masked by the C conditional. but this only holds IF C conditionals are guaranteed to return [0 or 1].

ps - i also realize that it is probably compiler dependent, but what does the ansi standard say about this?

Comment: Shouldn't it be (shouldSend != 0)?  Using !!shouldSend is an evil trick.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Standard specifies that the result is always integer value equals to 0 or 1

> **6.5.8** Relational operators
>
> Each of the operators < (less than), >
>   (greater than), <= (less than or equal
>   to), and >= (greater than or equal to)
>   shall yield 1 if the specified
>   relation is true and 0 if it is
>   false.92) The result has type int.

Comment: +1, quite surprising that it does indeed specify that behavior.  Over time I just assume that the spec would be more likely to say "returns 0 or random roll of the dice"

Comment: This leads to the idiom I've seen used since before there was a standard: `!!somevalue` which has the same truth value, but which is now guaranteed to be exactly 0 or 1.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't matter if it is specified or not.  It is best to always test against false and be explicit about your or-equals values.  This removes any worry about compiler implementations and is clearer and more maintainable.

Comment: That's actually relevant, since you could use & and | operators as logic operators WITHOUT short-circuiting.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than right shifting and left shifting back again to clear the LSB, I would bitwise-and it with 0xFE:

```
register = register & 0xFE;
```

[edit: assuming register is 8 bits. If not, adapt right hand operand as necessary]

But yes, if shouldSend is a result of a conditional test then it is guaranteed by the standard to be either 0 or 1. If there's any doubt about whether shouldSend could be generated from anywhere else it would be wise to put in the sort of precaution you have, or something like

```
register = register | (shouldSend ? 1 : 0);
```

Comment: The idiom I've seen used since before there was a standard: `!!somevalue` which has the same truth value, but which is now guaranteed to be exactly 0 or 1.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  This is guaranteed in C99.  I don't have the C89 spec handy.  Of course, compiler implementers have been known to make mistakes on occasion so YMMV.

C99 specifies the following in paragraph 6 of *6.5.8 Relational operators*:

> Each of the operators **<** (less than), **>** (greater than), **<=** (less than or equal to), and **>=** (greater than or equal to) shall yield 1 if the specified relation is true and 0 if it is false.

The same or similar clauses appear in paragraph 3 of *6.5.9 Equality operators*, paragraph 3 of *6.5.13 Logical AND operator*, and paragraph 3 of *6.5.14 Logical OR operator*.

Comment: This was true in the original K&R C and often depended on, so the standards had to follow suit.